# Как посчитать количество одинаковых элементов в двух массивах?

Tags: java, массивы

Даны два рандомно заполненных массива, которые сравниваются между собой. Нужно вывести количество одинаковых элементов... Я нашла эти элементы, но не пойму как найти их количество.

Comment: вы можете использовать вложенный цикл или HashMap для этого.

Comment: Посчитать там где вы нашли. Добавьте код что бы ответить вам по конкретнее

Comment: import java.util.Arrays;
public class homeworklr12 {

     public static int[] inputData(int n, int minitem, int maxitem) {
      //n - размер  массива заполняемого целыми случайными числами из [minitem,maxitem]
       int[]  arr = new int[n];  
       for (int i = 0;i<n; i++) {
          arr[i]=(int)(Math.random()*(maxitem-minitem+1)+minitem);
       }
       return arr;
      }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
             int n=(int)(Math.random()*(200)+1);;
             int[] mass1 = new int[n];    mass1=inputData(n,100000,999999);/

Comment: Arrays.sort(mass1);
      for (int i = 0;i<mass1.length; i++)
      System.out.print(mass1[i]+", ");  
      System.out.println();
      
    
      int[] mass2 = new int[n];  
      mass2=inputData(n,100000,999999);//n,1,20

      Arrays.sort(mass2);
 for (int i = 0;i<mass2.length; i++)
  System.out.print(mass2[i]+", "); 
 System.out.println();

 for(int i=0;i<mass1.length;i++){
  int a=mass1[i];
  for(int j=0;j<mass2.length;j++) {
   if (a==mass2[j]) {
    System.out.print(a+",");
    break;
   }
  }
 }
          }
      }

Comment: Если вы получили исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый (плюсик и галочка слева от ответа)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте вложенный цикл и переменную для подсчета совпадений.

```java
int[] array1 = {2, 45, 34, 3, 123, 348, 67, 78, 57, 123, 345, 128, 22};
int[] array2 = {2, 46, 34, 3, 123, 348, 67, 78, 56, 123, 345, 126, 23};

int count = 0;

for (int value : array1) {
    for (int i : array2) {
        if (value == i) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы оптимизировать поиск, можно произвести сортировку данных массивов и последущий бинарный поиск каждого элемента наименьшего по размеру массива во втором. Таким образом сложность составит **2 * O(n*log(n)) + n * O(log(n))**, что намного быстрее, чем **O(n^2)**
Если функция бинарного поиска возвращает отрицательное значение, тогда такого элемента во втором списке нет, а если неотрицательное, тогда инкрементируем счетчик.

Answer (score 0):

1. Цикл должен быть бесконечным, или while (true). У тебя он не бесконечный, через 2 в 31й он прекратится, даже если пользователь не введет -1.
2. Сумма должна накапливаться с каждым числом. Это значит, что твой аккумулятор должен создаваться ДО входа в цикл. А результат печататься после выхода из цикла по break'у.

Answer (score 0):

Обходим первый массив. Для каждого элемента ищем дубликаты во втором массиве и записываем их количество. Получаем массив дубликатов: по скольку раз каждый элемент из первого массива встречается во втором массиве:

```java
int[] array1 = new int[10];
int[] array2 = new int[10];

// заполняем массивы случайными числами
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> {
    array1[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    array2[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
});

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array1));
// [7, 2, 1, 3, 8, 5, 1, 8, 0, 4]
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array2));
// [7, 2, 5, 8, 6, 1, 9, 5, 2, 6]

// получаем массив дубликатов
int[] duplicates = Arrays.stream(array1)
        .map(i -> (int) Arrays.stream(array2)
                .filter(j -> i == j)
                .count())
        .toArray();

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(duplicates));
// [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0]
```